# Eclipse-like maven pom.xml management in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ, and I am desperately missing all kinds of helpful functionality when it comes to managing maven dependencies in a non-trivial project structure.

For example, in Eclipse, there is the helpful warning when you are (by mistake?) overwriting a managed dependency version.

How do I get that same warning in IntelliJ to make sure I'm not overwriting a managed version I actually did not intend to overwrite?

Also, in Eclipse, when you hover over a dependency that is managed "upstream", it shows you what the version is, and you can jump to the location (pom.xml) where it is being managed. How do I get that in IntelliJ as well?

I have installed the [Maven Helper plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper), and that somewhat helps with dependencies, but it still does not offer the functionality that Eclipse supports out of the box.

Or, is there essentially an IntelliJ plugin somewhere that simply offers Eclipse-like maven pom.xml management functionality with all the bells and whistles?

Comment: I would remove the last question asking about a plugin suggestion, that is off-topic and may trigger people to vote to close the question.

Comment: Please note that there is nothing wrong with using multiple IDE's each with the own strengths and weaknesses.  I would suggest having a separate checkout for each IDE.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, in Eclipse, there is the helpful warning when you are (by mistake?) overwriting a managed dependency version.

Doesn't seem like the feature exists, please vote for: [IDEA-181023](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181023)

> in Eclipse, when you hover over a dependency that is managed "upstream", it shows you what the version is, and you can jump to the location (pom.xml) where it is being managed. How do I get that in IntelliJ as well?

For the managed dependencies there is an icon in gutter, where you navigate or see the managed dependency details:

[image]

Comment: I don't see that arrow. Does this not work when the dependency is managed in BOM that was imported? Or is this some kind of feature that requires a setting to be turned on or an additional plugin?

Comment: No configuration needed. I've updated the screenshot.It should work either in same pom or between parent/child pom files.